# VBA If filter show/does not show values

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I have been struggling with this for some time and would like to know where am I doing wrong.
I have some source data and the last column (AG) is an excel function that evaluates if there are some N/As in some columns. If yes, it shows "error", otherwise it shows "ok". 
In my code I would like for the macro to filldown the formulas in columns R to AG (that works fine) and to evaluate if there are some filtered errors. If there are some errors, I want it to stop (so that the user sees those filtred errors), if there are only "ok"s, I would like to show all the values (no filter).
Here is my code:

```
Sub macro()
With Worksheets("Source")
LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Sheets("Source").Select
Range("R2:AG2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("R2:AG" & LastRow)

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AG$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:="error"

Counter = Range("$A$1:$AG$" & 
LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
If Counter = 1 Then
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AG$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=33
Else
End If

End Sub
```

The idea is, if the counter (number of visible rows, so only the header) is equal to 1, there are no errors and the filter should be disabled, if there are some other visible rows, the filter stays (blank after "else" statement) and the user then sees those mistakes.
Problem is, the counter is always 1 even if there are some errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) is a **multi-area** range, so `.Rows.Count` will return the number of rows in the first area only!

You need to scroll the areas and sum their number of rows.

```
Dim area As Range
For each area in Range("$A$1:$AG$" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  counter = counter + area.Rows.Count
Next
```

Alternatively, since you only want to check if all is filtered, just check a double condition: one area only and one row only:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AG$" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  If .Areas.Count = 1 And .Rows.Count = 1 Then
    'All is filtered ! no error, remove filter
    Range("$A$1:$AG$" & LastRow).AutoFilter
  End If
End with
```

yet a third way, even simpler:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AG$" & LastRow)
  .AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:="error"
  If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count = .Columns.Count Then .AutoFilter 'no error
End with
```